# How to adjust both brightness and contrast of a TFT LCD display

Tags: lcd, display, tft, brightness

I am developing an HMI using the display "S039QWQ01HS" and I have the requirement to provide control to adjust the brightness and contrast of it.

For the brightness control, I have already configured a PWM timer to control the backlight of the LCD, but how can I adjust the contrast of the LCD?

I am using the emWin library to control the LCD display but I cannot find anything in the UserManual, neither in the Datasheet of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LCD has no interface for contrast control.

The only way you can control contrast is to modify the RGB pixel data sent to the display, so the data is already adjusted for contrast.